# C++ program crashing (has something to do with with dynamic memory)

Tags: c++, class, memory, dynamic

I'm having the weird crashing that occurs everytime it goes to the for loop to initialize each position to undefined. Can anyone shine light on why this is happening?
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
class MyPhoneBook
{
public:
    MyPhoneBook(int, string, string, string, string);
    MyPhoneBook();
    ~MyPhoneBook();

    void initialise(int, int, string, string, string, string);
    bool search(string&, int);
    bool find_free_pos();
    void add(); 
    void remove(); 
    void display(int);

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, MyPhoneBook& ph);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, MyPhoneBook& ph);

    private:
    int *recordid; 
    int *status; // -1 is no longer at this number, 0 is blocked, 1 is not blocked, 2 is free
    string *name, *areacode, *number, *group;
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv) 
    {
        cout << "test 1" << endl;
        MyPhoneBook *myphbk;                    // pointer that will point to an object of a MyPhoneBook class
        myphbk = new MyPhoneBook[100];          // now its using dynamic memory

        cout << "test 2" << endl;       //just for testing

        int pos = 0;
        for(pos = 0; pos < 100; pos++)          // initializing everything to undefined, and position to free (position is the second parameter sended in)
        {
            myphbk[pos].initialise( (pos+1) , 2 , "Undefined" , "Undefined" , "Undefined" , "Undefined");
        }

        cout << "test 3" << endl;       //just for testing
    }

return 0;

void MyPhoneBook::initialise(int recordid_,int status_, string name_, string     areacode_, string number_, string group_)
{
   //now assign them to private member variables
   *recordid = recordid_;
   *status = status_;
   *name = name_;
   *areacode = areacode_;
   *number = number_;
   *group = group_;
   //end of assigning
}
```

does anyone have any idea why can't my program reach the cout << "test 3" << endl part of the program without crashing?

Comment: _"does anyone have any idea why can't my program reach the cout << "test 3" << endl part of the program without crashing?"_ Your debugger points your nose upon it, if you'd use it stepping through your code probably.

Comment: Stop using pointers and `new`, your problems will disappear

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not paste the constructor of `MyPhoneBook` i can only guess, but the problem could be the lines

```
*recordid = recordid_;
*status = status_;
```

if you did not assign a valid address to `recordid` and `status` in the constructor, e.g. by

```
recordid = new int;
status = new int;
```

You might want to declare those member variables as a simple `int`.